# How do I get the 5th business day of the month in Oracle SQL 19?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, oracle19c

I want to get the fifth business day of each month for a given date using Oracle SQL 19. Examples:

- For date 9/8/2021, the date would be 9/8/2021 because this is the fifth business day of September 2021
- For date 1/21/2021, the date would be 1/8/2021 because this is the fifth business day of January 2021
- For date 2/17/2021, the date would be 2/5/2021 because this is the fifth business day of February 2021

I need to consider the following:

- Federal/bank holidays
- I cannot store the holidays in a table. I can only use CTEs

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any country has its own business holidays, and inside the same country, every region/state has also its own . You need a calendar stored somehow. Also there are holidays that are based not on days ( Easter is a good example ). You can obviously built your own CTE expression with the dates in holidays, but you will need to change it every year.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking a basic calendar table is a server detriment to virtually any application. However, since you do not have one you can generate one to satisfy your requirement. Before beginning however you need to clearly define exactly is meant by business day. For purposes here a business day is any day Mon-Fri that is not a declared a holiday. Now we can proceed. First generate a holiday calendar then generate a monthly calendar eliminating non-business days and assign a day number to the remaining days in month. Finally select the day number of interest.

```
with holiday_calendar ( h_date ) as 
     (Select date '2021-01-01' from dual union all  
      Select date '2021-10-18' from dual union all 
      Select date '2021-02-15' from dual union all 
      Select date '2021-05-31' from dual union all 
      Select date '2021-07-04' from dual union all 
      Select date '2021-09-06' from dual union all 
      Select date '2021-10-11' from dual union all 
      Select date '2021-11-11' from dual union all 
      Select date '2021-11-25' from dual union all 
      Select date '2021-12-25' from dual
     )  --select * from holiday_calendar;
   , month_business_calendar (dom, bus_day_num) as 
     ( select case when dom <= last_day(sysdate) --for_date_in) 
                   then dom 
                   else null
              end 
            , row_number() over(order by dom)
         from (select trunc(sysdate ,'mon') + (level-1) dom    
                from dual connect by level <= 31
              ) 
       where dom <= last_day(trunc(sysdate ))  
         and to_char(dom,'dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') not in ('sat','sun')          
         and dom not in (select h_date from holiday_calendar)
      order by dom        
     ) 
select dom  "5th Business Day" 
  from month_business_calendar 
 where bus_day_num = 5;
```

The next step, if desired, is wrapping the CTE in the above in a function and parameterize for a given month. Something like:

```
create or replace type monthly_business_day_calendar_typ is object
       ( day_of_month     date
       , business_day_num integer
       ) ; 

create type monthly_business_day_calendar_array 
    is table of monthly_business_day_calendar_typ; 

create or replace
function make_monthly_business_calendar(date_in date) 
  return  monthly_business_day_calendar_array 
is
    monthly_business_day_calendar monthly_business_day_calendar_array; 
begin 
    with holiday_calendar ( h_date ) as 
         (Select date '2021-01-01' from dual union all  
          Select date '2021-10-18' from dual union all 
          Select date '2021-02-15' from dual union all 
          Select date '2021-05-31' from dual union all 
          Select date '2021-07-04' from dual union all 
          Select date '2021-09-06' from dual union all 
          Select date '2021-10-11' from dual union all 
          Select date '2021-11-11' from dual union all 
          Select date '2021-11-25' from dual union all 
          Select date '2021-12-25' from dual
         )  --select * from holiday_calendar;
       , month_business_calendar (dom, bus_day_num) as 
         ( select dom, row_number() over(order by dom)
             from (select trunc(date_in ,'mon') + (level-1) dom   
                    from dual connect by level <=  extract(day from last_day(date_in))
                  )
            where to_char(dom,'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') not in ('1','7')           
              and dom not in (select h_date from holiday_calendar)
         ) 
    select monthly_business_day_calendar_typ(dom, bus_day_num) 
      bulk collect 
      into monthly_business_day_calendar
      from month_business_calendar;
      
    return monthly_business_day_calendar; 

end make_monthly_business_calendar;
```

See [demos here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f6ecbfa8a5088c25f931a190507f07fc).

Note: Both versions return an empty record set when the requested business day number is greater then the number of business in the month. Example the 25th business day of October 2021, it only has 21.

Comment: that is a cool code, but the OP did not specify the country, neither the definition of a working day. Besides, this is not even realistic, you can have different holidays for different states in your own country. I live in Germany, and bank holidays in my state are different from other states. The whole approach does not make any sense. Every year you will need to adapt it. Nothing against your code, it is the best approach to the question itself, but the whole idea does not make any sense from a software perspective,